# How to pass an unqualified file name to a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I got some Powershell code from the answer to a different question and created this script, modifying it slightly so I could pass in the file name.

```
$file = [System.io.File]::Open($Args[0], 'Open', 'Read', 'None')
Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
$null = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
$file.Close()
```

It works fine if I run it (from a Powershell window) with an unqualified file when in my home directory or with a fully qualified file name in any directory. The script is lockfile.ps1 in a utilities folder on my path and these calls all work as expected.

```
C:\Users\SteveC.AFRICA> . lockfile abc.txt
C:\Users\SteveC.AFRICA> lockfile abc.txt
C:\Users\SteveC.AFRICA> lockfile .\abc.txt
C:\Users\SteveC.AFRICA> lockfile D:\Junk\abc.txt
```

However, when the current directory is not my home directory, I need to fully qualify the file name even for files in the current directory. So this call works

```
D:\Junk> lockfile D:\Junk\abc.txt
```

but these do not

```
D:\Junk> lockfile abc.txt
D:\Junk> lockfile .\abc.txt
```

both reporting the following error, indicating they are expecting to find the unqualified file named in my home directory.

```
Exception calling "Open" with "4" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Users\SteveC.AFRICA\abc.txt'."
```

Why is this, and what do I need to do to allow scripts like this to correctly accept unqualified file names as parameters?

Comment: `$Args[0]` -> `(Convert-Path $Args[0])`

Comment: Great thanks. Want to make it an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you mixing two things: PowerShell path and provider (`FileSystem` provider, especially) path. This two things are different.

In PowerShell you can create drives as you pleased, for example:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Win -PSProvider FileSystem -Root C:\Windows
```

After that you can write like this:

```
Get-Content Win:\System.ini
```

Of course, if you write something like this:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines('Win:\System.ini')
```

it will fail, due to `ReadAllLines` does not know anything about PowerShell and its `Win` drive. You need to convert PowerShell path to `FileSystem` provider path before to passing it to file system APIs. It can be done with `Convert-Path` cmdlet:

```
Convert-Path Win:\System.ini
```

To <del>make it easy to mix this things</del> simplify transition to PowerShell, `FileSystem` provider automatically maps file system drives to PowerShell drives with same name. So, you normally do not notice distinction. But for relative paths it is not work that well, because [PowerShell current location and process current working directory are different things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36306812) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think that your mention of path and provider is more confusing than anything else. After some thought and play, it makes perfect sense. I made a script that displays the unconverted and converted versions of the file name passed in and it highlighted that the unconverted name remains relative while the converted one is fully qualified. Of course the .Net method requires a fully qualified name so it is necessary to convert the argument to qualify it.