# Why are my zip files saving in system32 instead of the directory Im currently in?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I currently have a script that will take files from a directory I am in, copy them to a folder in the same directory, and then zip that into example.zip -- The only problem is that when I try to zip them using:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
  # Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
```

that zip file $zipfilename is saved to **C:\Windows\system32** instead of **C:\myDir\env\filesToZip** where I am currently at. Any idea why this would be happening instead of creating the zip file in the directory I executed the PowerShell script from?

Comment: PowerShell current location is not the same thing as process working directory. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306312)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [PetSerAl hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453659/why-are-my-zip-files-saving-in-system32-instead-of-the-directory-im-currently-in/46454963#comment79863167_46453659), .NET methods will default to the current working directory of the *process* (not necessarily that of powershell) when resolving relative path names.

Use `Resolve-Path` to resolve the path using the current location in powershell:

```
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
  $sourcepath = Resolve-Path $sourcedir
  if($sourcepath.Provider -ne 'FileSystem'){
    throw 'File system path expected for $sourcedir'
  }

  $destinationpath = Resolve-Path $zipfilename
  if($destinationpath.Provider -ne 'FileSystem'){
    throw 'File system path expected for $zipfilename'
  }

  $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcepath.ProviderPath, $destinationpath.ProviderPath, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
```